# jQuery plugin for building formulas by dragging and dropping

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to provide a back-end application to my customers, where they can set-up some rules by dragging and dropping, which would be processed on page call.

This is how it should work:  There are some basic elements of which the customer can build some `IF` blocks, e.g.

`<request_url> CONTAINS <term_xyz>`

`<agent> EQUALS 'Chrome'`

and so on. Now I'm looking for an jQuery plug-in to provide an easy drag and drop solution for concatenating these block to a formula using boolean operators, like

`((condition_1 OR condition_2) AND condition_3) OR (condition_3 AND condition_4)`

With this formula I can trigger some operations, so in the end there would be an instruction like

`IF <formula> THEN <do_something>`

which allows my customers to build absolutely flexible instructions.

My question is now: *Is there any ready-to-use jQuery plugin which can be used to build this formula via drag and drop based on the conditions?*

Note: I know how to handle and code this functionality in my application to process these instructions, but I need some help to get the formula with all round brackets and boolean operators from front-end. **And** I also know of jQuerys "Droppable" and "Sortable", but that's only the last option for me to build it on my own with these.

Comment: can you build formula string from drag and drop. if yes then you can simply build string and get boolean value of string by eval().

Comment: Have you read my question? "Is there any jQuery plugin which can be used to build this formula via drag and drop based on the conditions?" I want to know *if* there is any ready-to-use plugin for this drag and drop action.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once needed a script to build compley AND/OR rules and used [jQuery Query Builder](http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/).

It doesn't support drag&drop by default but has [a plugin](http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/plugins.html#sortable) (that I never used).

At the least you could take this as a starting point and expand it to fit your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That sounds really good. I'll give it a try definitely, but this could take some days as I've only sparse time for this project.

Comment: This seems to do it for me. Without drag'n'drop, but building a query is very intuitive, so 1st price goes to you :)